# CakePHP-2.0: How can i check missing action/ missiong view for a controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

If someone hits in the browser url bar with this http://mysite/users/unknownaction then i get error.

I want to catch that error and redirect to http://mysite/  .

How can i do this in CakePHP-2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in production mode as Hugo suggests, missing URLs will [throw a `NotFoundException`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#NotFoundException) which, by default, generates a standard "404 Not found" page. If you wish to change this behavior, you will have to look at the documentation for [handling exceptions in CakePHP 2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Create a file "app_error.php" on "app" folder.

```
<?php 

  class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
    function error404($params, $messages) {
      $this->Session->flash($messages);
      $this->controller->redirect(array('controller'=>'welcome', 'action'=>'index'));
      parent::error404($params);
    }
  }

?>
```

You can save error message on session flash before redirect.

Comment: That didn't work, i got error, Error: The action abcd is not defined in controller UsersController

Error: Create UsersController::abcd() in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php.

Comment: Change cake debug mode to "0", for use production mode.

Comment: production mode doesn't help .